# What technologies should be applied to create Animation in iPhone/iPad application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm new in Cocoa-Touch.

Please look at this links:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cab8CB_Lzbw

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8c8KA1uZ9F8&feature=autoplay&list=PL6EFB1A1E5CAA7666&lf=results_main&playnext=1

**I really want to learn technologies that used here for creating that  Animations.**

What should I use, it's regular animation? Or it's regular pictures animated programatically with Core Animation?

**Any tutorials, and ideas are really appreciated.**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying technology to all iOS graphics is Open GL ES. Now, Open GL is a pretty low level graphics frameworks, so that it is usual to use a higher-level framework build on top of Open GL to build complex applications. Of course, a basic knowledge of Open GL is always useful, and sometimes even when using a higher-level framework, necessary.

Core Animation is just one of those higher level frameworks built on top of Open GL, and a very advanced one, as to that; though, it still offer some complexity, and sometimes it is not easy finding documentation or samples about doing advanced things.

One broadly used graphic/game framework is [Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) for the iPhone, which also support integration with physics engines, like [Chipmunk](http://chipmunk-physics.net/) or [Box2D](http://box2d.org/), to create realistic cinematic effects. My suggestion would be to give it a try, since it is very easy to use.
It is very well supported and you will find a lot of recipes for doing common things like those in the videos you linked. Cocos2d is a 2D graphic framework. If you are interested in 3D as well, you could give a look to its 3D cousin, Cocos3d. My guess is that apps like those you linked could be surely made through Cocos2d.

Core Animation will give you more possibilities; Cocos2d an easy learning curve. Cocos2d is really aimed at games, but, it directly allows for other kinds of apps.

More options are [openFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc) and [Cinder](http://libcinder.org/). They are specifically aimed at "creating coding", like in applications mixing different technologies, like Open Gl, audio, etc. Those frameworks are also supported, but I haven't worked yet with them, so I cannot really say anything. If you go to their web sites, you will have quickly a glimpse at the kind of applications that are built by using them.

A more advanced option is [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/). As far as I understand, it is more aimed at professional development, i.e., not casual. You will need to adopt a whole workflow about building and integrating the 3D models in your app.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think that animations are made using UIKit and CoreAnimation.
I don't know very good tutorials, but some basics you can get from [Graphics and Animation tutorials of Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)